# CSS animations infinite vs Javascript timer

Tags: performance, cordova, css-animations, performance-testing, dom-events

While developing an HTML5 game (phonegap) to be played in poor devices (with Android 2.3 browser) I wonder if there are any tests of performance comparing CSS animations **infinite** vs JavaScript driven animations loop?

Something like;

```
animation: bounce 5s infinite;
-webkit-animation: bounce 5s infinite;
```

VS

```
var slidesInSlideshow = 3;
    var slidesTimeIntervalInMs = 2000;

    $scope.currentSlide = 1;
    var slideTimer =
        $timeout(function interval() {
            $scope.currentSlide = ($scope.currentSlide % slidesInSlideshow) + 1;
            slideTimer = $timeout(interval, slidesTimeIntervalInMs);
        }, slidesTimeIntervalInMs);
```

According to [Mozilla dev article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations), even simple animations can often perform poorly in JavaScript (unless they're well made).

Comment: I'm a huge promoter of pure CSS animations and such, but for something like a slideshow a mix of CSS and javascript works the best. [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) is a great tool for things like this

Comment: Thanks Zach for the info. Green sock! You remembered me of 2009! when I programmed something with flash action script ;) I still remember greensock for flash animations..